# AngularJS - Create a Module or a Service?

Tags: angularjs

Let me explain the situation first. I have an App "MyApp" that is used in one page to create some customizable product, and in this App I have 4 controllers. I have 4 buttons (one per controller) that let the user add items (totaly different objects).

What I want to acheive is to open a lightbox with an autocomplete field when the user click on a button. Of course the autocomplete should get from the API from different routes (depending on the controller). So my idea was to make the controller handle the call to the lightbox and get the result.

So In the scenario, is it better to create a Module that handle all the DOM creation of the lightbox/autocomplete form and passing it the URL to get the autocomplete results from ? and inject it in my MyApp.
Or to create a Service/Factory that does the same job and inject it in each Controllers ?

My concern is that a Module may be overthinking this, and that a service may have too much DOM specifics in it.

How would you do it ?

Nota : I'm new to AngularJS ;-)

Comment: DOM manipulation should be done by directives.

Comment: Yes but a Directive should be "small" in best practice, here I would have some logic to do, so maybe a Directive inside a Module you mean ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could do something like that. I'd personally try to keep it in a lightbox directive, see how that could be done. Use all your API calls as input parameters to the directive, that way the directive itself isn't that complicated.

Comment: it feel weird to pass a URL as a parameter of a directive. I don't why but it does to me ^^ The lightbox should know what to URL to call for the autocomplete search and then to what object of what controller pass the result...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a directive for the lightbox creation? Then your html can dynamically reference the current state, pass it to the directive, which then calls your service. Something like...

```
<div lightbox={{state.current.name}}></div>

.directive('lightbox', function(state) {
    return lightboxService(state)...
```